# Button Click in Form1 send link to Form2

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, navigation, browser

i have a Form1 and Form2. in form1 at button click send to webBrowser1 in Form2:

```
Form2.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com/");
Form2.Show();
```

but dosen't work..help me please

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Error 1 It should be a reference to an object for the property, method or field is not static 'Form1.Form2.webBrowser1'

Comment: Is Form2 the class name? If so you would need to create an instance ( Form2 f = new Form2(); f.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com"); f.Show(); ) Something like this

Comment: thank you very much (Sascha) Work!!

Answer (score 1):

i tried the same example here. Its working. Are you sure webBrowser component in Form2 has public access modifier? The Browser component loads/uses IE as the browser. So IE is obviously shit and loads very slow. So wait up

Comment: How do I set the public access to Form2?

Comment: Form2 is already public, if not make the class public. Here you need to make the browser component which is a member of Form2 class as public/internal. Do this via browser property window in VS look for Modifiers. Or go to Designer code of Form2 and edit it manually.

Comment: gives me another error now "Error 1 It Should Be in reference to an object for the property, method or field is not static 'Form1.Form2.webBrowser1'"

Comment: Create an object of Form2 man. Form2 is not static class. 

Do this way

Form2 form2Obj = new Form2()
form2Obj.webBrowser.Navigate("google")
form2Obj.Show();